# Unable to create a database using Mongo Java drivers

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new to mongo DB and just learning the basics right now. I'm trying to display the names of my current databases:

```
try {
        // Creates a new instance of MongoDBClient and connect to localhost
        // port 27017
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);

        mongoClient.getDB("myMongoDB");

        List<String> listofDB= mongoClient.getDatabaseNames();

        for(String dbName : listofDB){
            System.out.println(dbName);
        }



    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The only database it prints out are `admin` and `local`. `myMongoDB` does not appear. When I go on the shell and type in `show databases`, `myMongoDB` also doesn't appear. I'm really confused since by using the `.getDB()` method, if the String passed into that method is not a name of a current database, then mongo would create a database of that name.. [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/getting-started-with-mongodb-and-java-part-i)

I am using the following dependency:

```
            `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
            </dependency>`
```

Answer (score 2):

This will not print myMongoDB, as it is not yet created.
You need to do some transactions, like create collection, insert data into collection.
Then it will be shown into that list.
Only choosing a db doesn't create a database in mongo DB.

As default behaviour of mongodb is to create a database lazily, untill a document insert is made.

You can follow this link to do some operations on mongo using java driver:
http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/2.13/getting-started/quick-tour/

If you want to create collection using command line than you can follow this link:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/

Answer (score 1):

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
MongoCursor<String> dbsCursor = mongoClient.listDatabaseNames().iterator();
while(dbsCursor.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(dbsCursor.next());
}
```

Also check your [dpath](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath) (because shell not returning your db, may be its not in right path)

try with `mongod --dbpath /your/path` .

Also FYI, database does not actually get created until you insert a document into a collection in the database which will implicitly create the collection and the database.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try manually creating the DB and then running the code? I dont think myMongoDB exists yet in this context. To make one in the shell do `use myMongoDB`

EDIT: You also must put in at least one collection into the DB for it to be created. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_create_database.htm

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [link](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/Mongo.html#getDB-java.lang.String-), `getDB` method has been deprecated. Use `MongoClient.getDatabase(String databaseName)` method instead to create.

MongoDB creates a collection implicitly when the first document is saved into a collection. The `createCollection()` method explicitly creates a collection only and only if an options object is passed to it as an argument. Go through [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/) for further information